# Windows Universal 10 force download language resource

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, culture

We are creating a Windows 10 Universal App in 3 different languages, one of them being minoritary (Basque). During our local testing we could change to any of them, but when installing the app from the Windows Store the Basque resources are not available unless Basque is listed as one of the OS languages.

We've set the [NeutralResourcesLanguage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to Basque, hoping that the Basque resources would get embedded in the app, so they were always available, but to no avail.

Is there any way to force the download of the Basque resources regardless of Basque being listed as a language at the OS level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to force the download of the Basque resources regardless of Basque being listed as a language at the OS level?

Yes, you can set the `Generate app bundle` to `Never` when you package your app.

If the bundle file is generated, then he will cut your application into different parts to optimize the download. For language resource, it will only download the resources file relevant to the language of the device. If you don't have the corresponding Windows-Language-Pack installed, the app will not show the related language for that property which is pointing to the resources file.

For more information, you can refer to [Dynamically change the language of a universal app](http://www.guruumeditation.net/en/dynamically-change-the-language-of-a-universal-app/).

Comment: Well, that didn't solve our problem because we have had submited to the store before using a bundle and it doesn't allow us to go back, but it leaded us to, which has solved our problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802124/use-all-culture-versions-of-resources-files-in-uwp-app